# "The directory name is invalid" in Windows using os.makedirs with a folder named "aux"

Tags: python, windows

I'm trying to create a folder that is valid according to the lib `os` in Windows.

```
# Replace <user>
filePath = r"C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Temp\aux")
if not os.path.exists(filePath) and os.access(os.path.dirname(filePath), os.W_OK):
    os.makedirs(filePath)
```

But it failes with the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\<user>\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3267, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-8-a7b7e2731f40>", line 1, in <module>
    os.makedirs(filePath)
  File "C:\Users\<user>\Anaconda3\lib\os.py", line 221, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
NotADirectoryError: [WinError 267] The directory name is invalid: 'C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Temp\aux'
```

The problem? [You can't use "aux" as a folder name in Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/fileio/naming-a-file).

Is there a workaround in python to:

- "Really" check if the folder is valid (the "if" in the code above is not enough)
- Create the folder anyway?

Comment: The way to check to see if the folder is valid is to try to create it, and handle the error.

Comment: In an other circumstance you might want to use [`exist_ok=True`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.makedirs). In your case however you want to know that it did not create the directory.

Comment: DOS device names are reserved by user-mode code in the system runtime library, not by the filesystem driver in the kernel. So we can create a file or directory with a reserved DOS-device name by using a local-device path -- i.e. a fully-qualified path prefixed by "\\\\.\\" or "\\\\?\\". But it won't be accessible to programs that only support classic DOS paths.

Comment: [Here's a link to documentation for everything you could want to know about naming files/folders in Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/FileIO/naming-a-file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, filesystem operations are where it's [Easier to Ask for Forgiveness than Permission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11360858/what-is-the-eafp-principle-in-python).

The best way to do this is to try to create the directory, catch the `OSError` if it fails, and then handle the failure.

Comment: What would be the correct way to check in this case?

Comment: Just call `os.makedirs`. If it succeeds, it succeeds. If the directory name was invalid, you'll get a `NotADirectoryError` like you observed.